# how to add package into other test sources in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I would like to know how can one add a package into Other Test Sources in netbeans, to be specific in the Other Test Sources usually there is subfolder /src/test/ressources which contains , what I would like to do is to add my own package, but whenever I try to do this, it places my package to the source packages I have tried to change the location on the dialog window for package creation it only offers me three choices (Source Packages, Test Packages and Project Ressources).

N.B If it may help my project had no test package, I added it manually and am working on a maven java project and my version of netbeans is 8.0.2

Comment: NetBeans 8.1 is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for package  to show up in TestPackages it needs to be a subdirectory of  `src/test/java` ( `src/test/ressources` is not under `src/test/java/` )

One way to do it manually would be:

1. Go to the Files tab
2. Select the src folder
3. Right-click for pop-up menu  New -> Folder and enter test
4. Select the test folder use the pop-up New -> Folder enter java
5. Select the new java folder , New -> Folder and enter your package name,
6. Select that folder and choose New -> Java Class to put a java file in that folder.

A far easier way would be:

1. Select the project in projects window
2. Right-click for pop-up menu, Select New -> Other ...
3. Choose Category Unit Tests, File Type JUnit Tests
4. Enter class and package name on the next dialog and